# Shopify adding a class to an existing class if condition is true

Tags: shopify, liquid

Currently working on shopify theme and I'm trying to hide the sold out variants of a product. The theme is prestige if that matters or not.

I'm trying to do it the easy way since no other variants available works for me. What I'm trying to do is to add a class to an existing class if the product variant quantity is 0.

Example:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
{% if variant.inventory_quantity == 0 %}class{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

How my code looks:

```
{%- for value in option.values -%}

 <li class="HorizontalList__Item {% for variant in product.variants %}{% if variant.inventory_quantity < 1 %}{{ variant.inventory_quantity}}{% endif %}{% endfor %}">
      <input id="option-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.parentloop.index0 }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}" class="SizeSwatch__Radio" type="radio" name="option-{{ forloop.parentloop.index0 }}" value="{{ value | escape }}" {% if value == option.selected_value %}checked="checked"{% endif %} data-option-position="{{ option.position }}">
      <label for="option-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.parentloop.index0 }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}" class="SizeSwatch">{{ value }}</label>
 </li>    

{%- endfor -%}
```

I used {{variant.inventory_quantity }} to see what returns and it returns 0 for all. Then I removed {% if variant.inventory_quantity < 1 %} to see what's wrong and it returned all product variant quantity in my case 014673.

Because of the {%- for value in option.values -%} it checks all at once and it adds the class for all list even if the variant invetory quantity it's 0 or not.

Is there a way to append that class to the list outside the code if variant.inventory_quantity == 0?

Or something like if option is disabled to hide the list entirely? Because I'm checking if the variant is available or not here:

```
<select id="product-select-{{ product.id }}" name="id" title="Variant">
            {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
              <option {% if variant == selected_variant %}selected="selected"{% endif %} {% unless variant.available %}disabled="disabled"{% endunless %} value="{{ variant.id }}" data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money }}</option>
            {%- endfor -%}
          </select>
```

In my case the product variant 38 has quantity 0. Link to example https://lizzetstore.ro/collections/paltoane/products/palton-asimetric-negru

Comment: When you are dealing with multiply options (a.k.a color/size/etc...) it's best to use JS to set the sold class. Using only liquid will be almost impossible without at least relying on some JS logic. So the moment the user select a different size/color and that combination is available your logic will fail. ( except if you create multiply combinations of different markup for the different option combinations - I don't recommend it )

Comment: I have only one variant option, that's size and I want to achieve to hide when a client wants to see a product and a variant has 0 stock, right now it's checking if the variant has stock or not but it just disable the buy button when you press the variant with 0 stock. All I want is to hide it, not displaying it at all. I have only one option and I don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case if you are SURE that there will be a single variant you can do this.

```
<ul>
  {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
    <li {% unless variant.available %}class="soldout"{% endunless  %}>
      <input type="radio" name="id" value="{{variant.id}}" id="variant-{{variant.id}}" {% unless variant.available %} disabled{% endunless %}>
      <label for="variant-{{variant.id}}">{{ variant.option1 }}</label>
    </li>
  {%- endfor -%}
</ul>
```

You don't need the select that you are generating. We are using the radio instead to pass the `name="id"` input.

Please have in mind that this will work only if you have a single option! This means that if you have an additional option it will not work properly.

But this is the way to do it without the use of any javascript.

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm, two minor code errors, you used {% endif %} instead of {% endunless %}, I adapted a little bit to my case but it worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately @drip I discovered a bug today doing some testing on my code and I saw that code that we write has some bugs. For example you select size variant 40 and when you add it to cart it will add the first size variant that the product has and not the variant 40, it's weird, I don't know why is this..

Comment: @BogdanDutca did you remove the select? You need only the radio buttons `name="id"` nothing else should have `name="id"`.

Comment: {{ variant.option1 }} i think this is the problem

Comment: {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
  <li class="HorizontalList__Item {% unless variant.available %}nuAreStock{% endunless %}">
 <input class="SizeSwatch__Radio" type="radio" name="id" value="{{variant.id}}" id="variant-{{variant.id}}" {% unless variant.available %} disabled{% endunless %}>
                  <label for="variant-{{variant.id}}" class="SizeSwatch">{{ variant.option1 }}</label>
</li>    
 {%- endfor -%}..

I think {{ variant.option1 }} is the problem, because it returns the value of the variant's first option and I think that's why always will select first size variant

Comment: `{{ variant.option1 }}` returns the option not the variant, a.k.a the size. I'm asking agian did you detele this element `<select id="product-select-{{ product.id }}" name="id" title="Variant">` from your form?

Comment: I saw the problem, seems to work now, I will test more on the offline version to see if the is no problem. Thank you again for the assist @drip