# Highlight navigation menu link based on domain, not path, except for one page

Tags: javascript, css, navigation, liquid

I have two nav links in a menu at the top of a Shopify site. The menu is created/edited in admin nav settings. I need the menu link for #1 to remain highlighted for every page of the website, unless on #2 page.

The liquid looks like this:

```
<span class="inline-menu">
{% for link in linklists[section.settings.menu].links %}
<a class="inline-menu__link" href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
</span>
```

And then html renders like this:

```
<span class="inline-menu">
<a class="inline-menu__link" href="/">Pure Luxury Beauty</a>
<a class="inline-menu__link" href="/pages/pl-pro">PL Pro</a>
</span>
```

This javascript got me partially there, but if I navigate away from the homepage I lose the "current" class.

```
$(function() {
  $("a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("href") == window.location.href) {
      $(this).addClass("current");
    }
  });
});
```

I'm looking for a way to keep that "current" class on the first link for every page of the site, but then switch to the second link when only on that page.

Comment: Do you use absolute or relative links? Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: It's a shopify site, and those links render as relative. I can't find a reproducible example. Although here is one that appears to have the same issue I'm trying to solve. Where the nav menu at the top of the page is highlighted on the home page, but loses it's "active" class when going to any other page. https://www.bellamihair.com/

Comment: WIth  reproducible example I mean the code you posted. Right now you're referencing some ```a``` tags which we dont know how they look like.

Comment: Sure, I just edited the post accordingly I believe.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (window.location.href == 'https://yourdomain.com/pages/pl-pro')
{
    $('#l1').removeClass ('current');
    $('#l2').addClass ('current');
}
```

```css
.current
{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="inline-menu">
<a class="inline-menu__link current" href="/" id="l1">Pure Luxury Beauty</a>
<a class="inline-menu__link" href="/pages/pl-pro" id="l2">PL Pro</a>
</span>
```

Comment: That would fully work if I was writing the html. But I forgot to mention the crucial detail that I'm working in Shopify and the nav menu is made in the admin UI. If I add the current class to the liquid, all the links get the current class. I updated the post if you could take another look. Thanks

Comment: @powerdown I dont know shopify or liquid but you probably need to set the class name based on a condition: https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/tags/conditional-tags
This might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59647128/shopify-adding-a-class-to-an-existing-class-if-condition-is-true